# Gradle Composite build ignores resolutionStrategy customization for multi projects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, microservices, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use [Gradle Composite Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) to build a multiple independant projects in my solution. Any plugin that overrides `resolutionStrategy` seems to be ignored when building from a Composite build.

**Project Layout**

```
| master               <<Composite Build>>
| |\ -- settings.gradle
| |  -- build.gradle
| library1
| |\ -- settings.gradle
| |  -- build.gradle
| library2
| |\ -- settings.gradle
| |  -- build.gradle
| mulitProj             << Multi Project>>
| |\ -- settings.gradle
| |  -- build.gradle
| - multiProjChild1
| | |\ -- build.gradle
| - multiProjChild2
| | |\ -- build.gradle
```

**Composite Build (master):**

```
settings.gradle
===============

includeBuild('../library1') {
  dependencySubstitution {
    substitute module('com.company:library1') with project (':')
   }
}

includeBuild('../library2') {
  dependencySubstitution {
    substitute module('com.company:library2') with project (':')
   }
}

includeBuild('../multiProj')
```

**Builds (library1, library2, multiProject):**

Note that all `build.gradle` files are using spring dependency management to share common library versions.

```
build.gradle
============
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(               
            'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.1.RELEASE'
        )
    }
}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

  dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
      dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.3'
      dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.3'
      ...
    }
  }
}

...

dependencies {
  compile(
    'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core',
    'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:annotations',

...
```

When I build any of the projects (library1, library2, multiProj) individually, they build fine.

When I build the Composite build, `master`, dependency resolution customization provided by `dependencyManagement` is ignored for the multi-project.

I have written my own Gradle Plugin to see if I could reproduce this. It turns out that the `Closure` in `resolutionStrategy.eachDependency` is never called when building a multi-Project build in a Composite Build.

For example:

```
/** Gradle plugin to resolve dependencies **/
class DependencyResolverPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

@Override
public void apply(Project project) {

    project.configurations.all {

        // Resolve managed dependency versions
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            //    !!
            //    This Closure is never called when this plugin is
            //    applied to a multi project build, which is built
            //    in a composite build
            //    !!

            if (details.requested.version == null) {
               //Replace the version with the managed dependency version
            }
         }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like resolution strategy customization to continue to work when used with a Composite Build.

Answer (score 0):

This is a current, known limitation of composite-builds. It is discussed in [this topic](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/947).